# How to bind json data into Span tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a json like below

```
[
 {"label":"Finder1","count":3},
 {"label":"Finder2","count":1},
 {"label":"Finder1 & Finder2","count":1}
]
```

I want to show the data in frontend in span tag. 
for ex:

```
Finder1 (3)
Finder2 (1)
Finder1 & Finder2 (1)
```

Please help me the little java script to achieve this.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:Loop through the data and construct the desired string with it.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    $(function(){
     var arr=[
      {"label":"Finder1","count":3},
      {"label":"Finder2","count":1},
      {"label":"Finder1 & Finder2","count":1}
     ];
        var str='';
     $.each(arr,function(index){
         str=str+arr[index].label+" ("+arr[index].count+")<br>";
     });

     $("#data").html(str);
    });
    </script> 

    <body>
    <span id="data"></span>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `map`:

```
var html = '<span>' + arr.map(function (el) {
  return [el.label, ' (', el.count, ')'].join('');
}).join('<br/>') + '</span>';

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/ba8d3vbL/)

Comment: Thank you aundy..it helped me to drive in fine tune.